# Possible to use angular-cli in other projects?

Tags: angular-cli

I would like to use the angular-cli in an existing angular2 project and use it to generate components and such. What configuration is needed to achieve this? I thought including `angular-cli.json` would suffice. Any tips?

Answer (score 0):

> **Possible, yes. Suggested, no.**

It is possible, you would need to run `ng init` within your project's root directory. Without doing this the CLI will not be able to determine the root of your project. But the caveat/consequence is that you get ALL of the CLI with it, including build process and unit tests. So if you're not going to be using those other wonderful features, I don't think it makes sense to use the CLI for that.

**Alternatives**:

- John Papa (and others) have put out snippets for many editors/IDE's that you can use to spin up your files quickly.
- You can setup a CLI project in another directory and use that for your scaffolding and copy over the files. (not a great options, but still an option)